# Tensor multiplication in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to carry out tensor multiplication in NumPy/Tensorflow.

I have 3 tensors- `A (M X h), B (h X N X s), C (s X T)`.

I believe that `A X B X C` should produce a tensor `D (M X N X T)`.

Here's the code (using both numpy and tensorflow).

```
M = 5
N = 2
T = 3
h = 2
s = 3
A_np = np.random.randn(M, h)
C_np = np.random.randn(s, T)
B_np = np.random.randn(h, N, s)

A_tf = tf.Variable(A_np)
C_tf = tf.Variable(C_np)
B_tf = tf.Variable(B_np)

# Tensorflow
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(A_tf)
    p = tf.matmul(A_tf, B_tf)
    sess.run(p)
```

This returns the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_2' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [5,2], [2,2,3].
```

If we try the multiplication only with numpy matrices, we get the following errors:

```
np.multiply(A_np, B_np)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,2) (2,2,3)
```

However, we can use `np.tensordot` as follows:

```
np.tensordot(np.tensordot(A_np, B_np, axes=1), C_np, axes=1)
```

Is there an equivalent operation in TensorFlow?

### Answer

In numpy, we would do as follows:

```
ABC_np = np.tensordot(np.tensordot(A_np, B_np, axes=1), C_np, axes=1)
```

In tensorflow, we would do as follows:

```
AB_tf = tf.tensordot(A_tf, B_tf,axes = [[1], [0]])
AB_tf_C_tf = tf.tensordot(AB_tf, C_tf, axes=[[2], [0]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ABC_tf = sess.run(AB_tf_C_tf)
```

`np.allclose(ABC_np, ABC_tf)` return `True`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
tf.tensordot(A_tf, B_tf,axes = [[1], [0]])
```

For example:

```
x=tf.tensordot(A_tf, B_tf,axes = [[1], [0]])
x.get_shape()
TensorShape([Dimension(5), Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])
```

Here is [tensordot documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot), and here is the relevant [github repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py).