# How to multiply one of the dimension of the multi dimension tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Tensor as below:

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3],name="output")
```

I want to multiply the last of the 3 dimension tensor.
I have tried this:

```
outputs_with_multiplier = y
outputs_with_multiplier[-1] = tf.multiply(outputs_with_multiplier[-1],tf.constant(2.0))
```

I received the following error:

```
  outputs_with_multiplier[-1] = tf.multiply(outputs_with_multiplier[-1],tf.constant(2.0))
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

I have check the following questions for reference, but I didn't found them helpful, may be because I didn't understood them.
1) [Tensorflow - matmul of input matrix with batch data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235555/tensorflow-matmul-of-input-matrix-with-batch-data)
2) [Tensor multiplication in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067338/tensor-multiplication-in-tensorflow)

Kindly, help me multiply the Tensors dimension so that it work smoothly.

For example if this is my `y = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[2,5,7],[8,9,10],[0,3,2]]` So I want to make it `outputs_with_multiplier = [[1,2,6],[2,3,8],[3,4,10],[2,5,14],[8,9,20],[0,3,4]]`

Please let me know if there is any solution to this.

Comment: Is there any answer to it? Please let me know what I can do to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do an item assignment but you can create a new `Tensor`. The key is to multiply the first 2 columns by 1 and the 3rd column by 2.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], name="output")
y = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0, 2.0]])
z = tf.multiply(x, y)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[2,5,7],[8,9,10],[0,3,2]]})
```

Comment: Will it yield what I am looking for? Let me check I will accept it if it is working.

Comment: When I tried to implement the logic  got this error: `ValueError: Tensor("Const:0", shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("prediction:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32).`

Comment: What must be the reason for this?

Comment: Please can you let me know?